# How to get Default value for a submitted records in KENTICO form

Tags: kentico

In my SSO application survey form, I missed to include staffNo. field to track the user inputs.
Later I included the column and the data shows only for those which has been submitted after that.

Please help me **how I can get default staff id value of respective past form records**.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a simple tool and using the API I would update the existing form records. You can find [API example here](https://docs.xperience.io/13api/content-management/form-data#Formdata-Updatingthedatarecordsofaform).

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is using Kentico API for update the form data which was mentioned above by Juraj.

Also you can try below option -

Kentico will create a table for each bizfrom with the following naming convention:

**Form_[your form name]**

So you can directly connect Database and apply update query with respecting data to update for past records.